# Noun Form of Faithful

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns

I am working on a quarter paper in which I compare two adaptations (adaptions?) of *Romeo and Juliet*. However, I am not entirely sure what word I can use as the noun form of `faithful`. My teacher said `fidelity` would do, but are there any other words that I could use to avoid repetition?

> My teacher expressly prohibited me from using `faithfulness`, so don't post that as an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you find for synonyms of "fidelity"??

Comment: The closest I could find was `loyalty` but that is more to a person than to a literary work.

Comment: Fidelity; constancy; loyalty (to the original).

Comment: Did you actually **look** at a thesaurus, even an online one?

Comment: Yes I did, but none of the words seem to fit.

Comment: Look again, at the synonyms for "faithfulness", in, say, Thesaurus.com.  Go beyond the first few lines.  There are several sections there.  One of them is what you need.

Comment: OK, so we are talking about whether an adaptation is *faithful* to the original work.  At first I thought this was about whether Romeo was *faithful* to Juliet or vice verse.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @HotLicks I have already done that, but none of the words seem to fit.

Comment: exactness
noun. accuracy, precision

    carefulness
    correctness
    definiteness
    definitiveness
    definitude

    exactitude
    faithfulness
    faultlessness
    nicety
    orderliness

    painstakingness
    preciseness
    promptitude
    regularity
    rigor

    rigorousness
    scrupulousness
    strictness
    truth
    unequivocalness

    veracity

Comment: fidelity
noun. conformity to a standard

    accuracy
    adherence
    adhesion
    attachment

    closeness
    constancy
    correspondence
    exactitude

    exactness
    faithfulness
    loyalty
    naturalism

    preciseness
    precision
    realism
    scrupulousness

    verism

Comment: **Diplomacy**. One often speaks of publishing *diplomatic editions* of texts that preserve every detail of the original's including typos, abbreviations, etc., up to in many cases original line breaks and pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some contexts, you could talk of the author's "adherence" to the original. Generally speaking, though, "faithfulness to the original" is the go-to option, so it's odd that it has been disallowed.